# How to detect the amount of time that specific application hasn't been using CPU?

Tags: c#, user-interface, batch-file, cmd, white-framework

I am trying to automate one third party application through user interface (using TestStack.White). But sometimes program freezes, since it is trying to load something during that time, it is in running stage as well... So I can't detect it by checking the status (not responding/running) in order to kill it and restart it. However during that time CPU usage is zero, so i was thinking about can I time it when CPU usage is zero for that application, if it is zero for let's say 5min restart the application.

Note: Application is running on Windows Server

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to measure the CPU usage in real-time only (AFAIK) using [typeperf](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490960.aspx):

```
@echo off
:check
for /f "delims=, tokens=2 skip=2" %%a in ('^
    typeperf  "\Process(EXENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION)\%% Processor Time" -si 300 -sc 1^
') do (
    set cpu=%%~a
    goto break
)
:break
if not %cpu:~0,2%==0. goto check

restart_the_process......
```

- `EXENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION` e.g. `Explorer`
- `-si 300` means 300 seconds or 5 minutes
- The example code assumes dot as decimal delimiter

Comment: Thanks... it is exactly what i was looking for